# Как правильно считать данные из файла?

Tags: c++

Дан текстовый файл:

```
1:1:6
2:0
3:2:1:4
4:0
5:2:2:3
6:0
```

как правильно считать его в двумерный вектор интов

задан список смежности графа, 1 столбец - вершины графа, 2 - количество его смежных вершин, 3 - смежные вершины
я пытался считать через два цикла for,считывал в char и проверял на двоеточие. Если двоеточие, переходил на следующий шаг цикла, иначе записывал в вектор g[i].push_back(char - '0').Проблема в том, что у меня не получилось записывать строки таких размеров, как в примере.

Comment: fscanf вполне можно

Comment: Считывать построчно, разделять по двоеточиям, конвертировать значения в int, раскладывать по векторам.

Comment: задан список смежности графа, 1 столбец - вершины графа, 2 - количество его смежных вершин, 3 - смежные вершины
я пытался считать через два цикла for,считывал в char и проверял на двоеточие. Если двоеточие, переходил на следующий шаг цикла, иначе записывал в вектор g[i].push_back(char - '0').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала вам нужна функция, которая считывает строку и превращает её в вектор интов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::vector<int> read(std::istream &is){
    std::vector<int> data;

    std::string line;
    getline(is, line);
    std::stringstream sstream(line);

    while(sstream){
        int i;
        sstream >> i;
        sstream.ignore(1);
        data.push_back(i);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Я для того, чтобы разбить строку на числа, использовал `std::stringstream`. К сожалению у `std::string` до сих пор нет метода `split`. Вы можете воспользоваться любым удобным для вас способом.
Теперь нужно просто вызывать полученную функцию до конца файла:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > data;

    //Вот тут вместо cin  нужно сделать открытие файла.
    //Что-то вроде std::ifstream stream("Имя_Файла");
    std::istream &stream = std::cin; 

    while(stream){
        data.push_back(read(std::cin));
    }
}
```